# How to set the content of a Gridstack panel in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gridstack

I would like to ask if it is possible to set dynamically the content of a gridstack panel, through one of its properties or in another way.

Comment: you can modifiy its DOM using jquery/javascript, what is your problem can you narrow it down to the specific issues

Comment: I wanted to be able to write something in the panel programmatically. I found the way I needed here : https://jsfiddle.net/ssfk1kfa/18/
Thank you for your answer.